# How can I stop Visual Studio Code from instantly assuming preprocessor directives (C++)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I noticed that whenever I use strings, cmath functions, etc. my code will still run even without adding in the specific #include <> at the top of my code. How can I stop this from happening so I can practice putting them in?

I've searched all over the web this question so I'm not sure if I'm looking at this wrong.

Comment: Header files can often include other header files. But for the system header files this is nothing you should rely on, and make it a habit to always include what you need explicitly. Unfortunately it's nothing the compiler can do about it, because the header files are clearly included, just not directly by you. It's just something you need to train to do to get all the good habits, which unfortunately can take years.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use. Also, please provide a [mre].